# pytorch RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Double but got scalar type Float

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am trying to implement a custom dataset for my neural network. But got this error when running the forward function. The code is as follows.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import numpy as np

class ParamData(Dataset):
    def __init__(self,file_name):
        self.data = torch.Tensor(np.loadtxt(file_name,delimiter = ','))    #first place
    def __len__(self):
        return self.data.size()[0]
    def __getitem__(self,i):
        return self.data[i]

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,in_size,out_size,layer_size=200):
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.layer = nn.Linear(in_size,layer_size)
        self.out_layer = nn.Linear(layer_size,out_size)

    def forward(self,x):
        x = F.relu(self.layer(x))
        x = self.out_layer(x)
        return x

datafile = 'data1.txt'

net = Net(100,1)
dataset = ParamData(datafile)
n_samples = len(dataset)

#dataset = torch.Tensor(dataset,dtype=torch.double)   #second place
#net.float()                                          #thrid place

net.forward(dataset[0])         #fourth place
```

In the file `data1.txt` is a csv formatted text file containing certain numbers, and each `dataset[i]` is a size 100 by 1 `torch.Tensor` object of dtype `torch.float64`. The error message is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\Wrong.py", line 33, in <module>
    net.forward(dataset[0])
  File "Z:\Wrong.py", line 23, in forward
    x = F.relu(self.layer(x))
  File "E:\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 87, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "E:\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1372, in linear
    output = input.matmul(weight.t())
RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Double but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'mat2' in call to _th_mm
```

It seems that I should change the dtype of the numbers in `dataset` to `torch.double`. I tried things like

- changing the line at the first place to `self.data = torch.tensor(np.loadtxt(file_name,delimiter = ','),dtype=torch.double)`
- changing the line at the fourth place to `net.forward(dataset[0].double())`
- uncommenting one of the two lines at the second or the thrid place

I think these are the solutions I have seen from similar questions, but they either give new errors or don't do anything. What should I do?

---

**Update:** So I got it working by changing the first place to

```
self.data = torch.from_numpy(np.loadtxt(file_name,delimiter = ',')).float()
```

which is weird because it is exactly the opposite of the error message. Is this a bug? I'd still like some explaining.

Comment: `.float()` on input after converting it to torch tensors worked for me as well.

Comment: Worked for me too ... I am confused for similar reasons

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Now that I have more experience with pytorch, I think I can explain the error message. It seems that the line

```
RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Double but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'mat2' in call to _th_mm
```

is actually refering to the weights of the linear layer when the matrix multiplication is called. Since the input is `double` while the weights are `float`, it makes sense for the line

```
output = input.matmul(weight.t())
```

to expect the weights to be `double`.

Answer (score 19):

**In short**: your data has type **double** but your model has type **float**, this is not allowed in pytorch because only data with the same dtype can be fed into the model.

**In long**:
This issue is related to the default dtype of PyTorch and Numpy. I will first explain why this error happens and then suggest some solutions(but I think you will not need my solution once you understand the principle.)

- PyTorch has a couple of dtypes https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html. Two of them are closely related to the issue you had:

1. `torch.float32`(aka `torch.float`)
2. `torch.float64`(aka `torch.double`)

- It's important to know the default dtype of PyTorch Tensors is `torch.float32`(aka `torch.float`). This means when you create a tensor, its default dtype is `torch.float32`.try: `torch.ones(1).dtype` . This will print `torch.float32` in default case. And also the model's parameters are of this dtype by default.
- In your case, `net = Net(100,1)` will create a model whose dtype of parameters are `torch.float32`

Then we need to talk about Numpy:

- The default dtype of Numpy ndarray is `numpy.float64`. This means when you create a numpy array, its default dtype is `numpy.float64`.try: `np.ones(1).dtype` . This will print `dtype('float64')` in default case.
- In your case, your data come from a local file loaded by `np.loadtxt`, so the data is first loaded as `dtype('float64')`(as a numpy array) and then converted to a torch tensor of dtype `torch.float64`(aka `torch.double`). This is what happens when you convert a numpy array to torch tensor: they will have the corresponding dtype.

I think now the issue is pretty clear, you have a model whose parameters are of `torch.float32`(aka `torch.float`) but tries to run it on data of `torch.float64`(aka `torch.double`). This is also what the error message tries to say:`Expected object of scalar type Double but got scalar type Float for argument`

Solutions:

1. You have alreay found one: convert your data to `torch.float32` by calling `tensor.float()`
2. You can also specify the dtype when load the data: `np.loadtxt(file_name,delimiter = ',',dtype="float32")`

Answer (score 1):

I came across this error while training a UNet in PyTorch. The training and test data was created from numpy arrays. Simply specifying the datatype while creating the tensors from numpy arrays resolved the error.

```
X_train, y_train = //read data files

train_x = torch.tensor(X_train, dtype=torch.float32) 

train_y = torch.tensor(y_train, dtype=torch.float32)
```